Swiftui and NStableView with NSArrayController - not KVC compliant
I have a simple example of an NSTableview using NSViewControllerRepresentable and a coordinator. The table and its ArrayController are instantiated via an .xib. The example runs fine, however if I try to add the two relevant files - the .xib and Coordinator code - to my real app, the app crashes due to the content array not being KVC compliant:

Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSUnknownKeyException', reason: '[<NSApplication 0x124e06160> valueForUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key contents.'

This is without actually trying to wire up the table to display anything, just adding the .xib and 1 other file containing the controller and Coordinator.
In the example and my app, the .xib shows an exclamation mark next to the Model Key Path in the Controller Content section of the binding inspector of the .xib. I presume this is because the binding isn’t really OK, but as I said, the example works fine.
Here is the code:
import SwiftUI


class Item: NSObject, Identifiable {
    @objc var id = UUID()
    @objc var name: String
    
    init(name: String) {
        self.name = name
    }
}


class TableViewController: NSViewController {
    @objc dynamic var contents: [Item] = []

    @IBOutlet weak var tableView: NSTableView!
    @IBOutlet var arrayController: NSArrayController!
}


struct TableVC: NSViewControllerRepresentable {
    var items: [Item]
    @Binding var selection: IndexSet

    
    func makeCoordinator() -> Coordinator {
        return Coordinator(self)
    }
    
    
    /// Gets called once - can't set delegate here as it is too early
    func makeNSViewController(context: Context) -> NSViewController {
        let tableVC =  TableViewController()
        
        tableVC.contents = items
        return tableVC
    }
        
    /// Gets called whenever when SwiftUI changes
    func updateNSViewController(_ nsViewController: NSViewController, context: Context) {
        guard let tableVC = nsViewController as? TableViewController else {return}
 
        /// don't seem to be able to set it earlier as in makeNSViewController
        tableVC.tableView?.delegate = context.coordinator
        context.coordinator.tableView = tableVC.tableView
        
        tableVC.contents = items
                
        if selection.isEmpty{
            tableVC.arrayController.setSelectionIndexes([])
        }
    }
    

    
    class Coordinator: NSObject, NSTableViewDelegate {
        var parent: TableVC
        weak var tableView: NSTableView?
        
        init(_ parent: TableVC) {
            self.parent = parent
        }
        
        func tableViewSelectionDidChange(_ notification: Notification) {
            guard let tableView = notification.object as? NSTableView else {return}
                                    
            DispatchQueue.main.async{
                self.parent.selection = tableView.selectedRowIndexes
            }
        }
    }
}

Can anyone show me what needs to be done to make the above KVC compliant?
Thanks!

Why for god's sake do you go back to stone-age (no offense, Cocoa )? Is there anything SwiftUI cannot do natively?

SwiftUI tableviews still leave a lot to be desired. Big chunks of my app require super fast update of hundreds of cells in many tables. Even view based tableviews are WAY too slow. Cell based tableviews are fine though. In this particular case the SWiftUI table just didn't cut it either - there is almost ALWAYS a show stopper somewhere if it gets remotely complicated.
